# Change layer color on zoom in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I had a problem with changing the color of a layer in Openlayers on zoom.
During initialization, I draw a heat map with data on atmospheric pressure. And at first everything is fine.
[image: Screenshot]

But after zooming or moving around the map, the color of the layer becomes more transparent.
[image: SCreenshot #2]

The layer is a LayerGroup in which the background layer is first added, and then the layer itself with the heat map is added.

```
class HeatMapLayer extends WeatherLayer {
  #style;
  #colorRange;
  #layer;
  #substrateLayer;

  constructor(ol_map, options = {}) {
    super(ol_map);
    const {
      colorRange, style,
    } = options;
    this.#colorRange = colorRange;
    this.#style = style;
    this.#substrateLayer = new SubstrateLayer(ol_map);
  }

  #createGeoJSONSource = features => new VectorSource({
    features: this.readGeoJSONFeatures(features),
  });

  #createLayer = features => new VectorImage({
    source: this.#createGeoJSONSource(features),
    style: this.#style,
  });

  loadData = ({ features }) => {
    this.isLoaded = true;
    const layers = this.layer.getLayers();
    if (!layers.values_?.length) {
      this.#layer = this.#createLayer(features);
      this.#layer.on("prerender", function (evt) {
        evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
      });
      this.#layer.on("postrender", function (evt) {
        evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      });
      const substrateLayer = this.#substrateLayer.getLayer(this.#layer.getSource().getFeatures());
      layers.push(substrateLayer);
      layers.push(this.#layer);
    } else {
      const [substrateLayer, layer] = layers.array_;
      substrateLayer.setSource(null);
      const source = this.#createGeoJSONSource(features);
      substrateLayer.setSource(this.#substrateLayer.getSource(source.getFeatures()))
      layer.setSource(null);
      layer.setSource(source);
    }
  }

  create = ({ intervals, opacity }) => {
    this.colorScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain(intervals)
      .range(this.#colorRange)
    return super.create(this.layerTypes.vectorGroup, { opacity });
  };

  destroy = () => {
    this.#substrateLayer.destroy();
  };
}

export default HeatMapLayer;
```

```
class SubstrateLayer {
  #layer;

  #layerPrerenderHandler = ({ context }) => {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "color";
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  }

  #layerPostrenderHandler = ({ context }) => {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "color";
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  };

  #createSubstrateLayer = features => new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      features,
    }),
    style: new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: '#888',
      })
    }),
  });

  #setListeners = () => {
    // this.#layer.on('prerender', this.#layerPrerenderHandler)
    this.#layer.on('postrender', this.#layerPostrenderHandler);
  };

  #removeListeners = () => {
    // this.#layer.un('prerender', this.#layerPrerenderHandler)
    this.#layer.un('postrender', this.#layerPostrenderHandler);
  };

  setVisible = value => this.#layer.setVisible(value)

  getSource = features => new VectorSource({
    features,
  });

  getLayer = features => {
    if (!this.#layer) {
      if (features) {
        this.#layer = this.#createSubstrateLayer(features);
        this.#setListeners();
        return this.#layer;
      }
    }
  };

  destroy = () => {
    this.#removeListeners();
  }
}

export default SubstrateLayer;
```